# Complex or Complicated?

Tags: meaning, word-difference

What is the difference between 'complex' and 'complicated', in semantics and usage?
I guess 'complex' is more technical; it's used in math, physics, engineering, grammar, etc. But what about non-technical use? Is there any difference between the two sets of examples bellow?

> - We have a complex relationship.
> - He is a complex person.
> - This problem is complex.
>
>   ---
> - We have a complicated relationship.
> - He is a complicated person.
> - This problem is complicated.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=complicated+problem%2C+complex+problem&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomplicated%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomplex%20problem%3B%2Cc0

Comment: *complex* = has many parts. *complicated* = difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

*complicated* is an adjective, while *complex* is either an adjective or a noun. The latter can be used to describe a structure:

> The new pharmacy complex is currently being built.

A problem regarding the human body:

> I was told I have a complex when I look down other people.

Also, a problem can be complex or complicated. Often a complicated problem is something more complex.

Comment: There is another difference worth noting - I feel that "complex" describes something regardless of the perspective. A complex concept is a concept that is incredibly intricate and precise. A complicated concept, however, is one that is difficult to understand from somebody's perspective. I might be reading too far into it though.

Answer (score 0):

Things that are **not easily explained or described** are often referred to as either **complex** or **complicated** interchangeably in daily usage. The interchangeability does not result in any loss of understanding. However, there are differences in meaning of the two words.

**Complex** comes from the Latin ***an aggregate of parts***
**Complicate** comes from the Latin ***to fold together***

**Complex** refers to a single thread of idea or subject which has many different parts, but which make **an identifiable whole** This is shown when it is used in another way which describes **a group of similar or related objects** :

> The hospital building **complex**
>   A personality **complex**

**Complicated** refers to how things **interact** or **interconnect** where there are several **different factors** involved :

> The street layout is **complicated**
>   Relationships can be **complicated**

There was a recent movie entitled: ***It's Complicated***